# What is the difference between viewModel() from the architecture components library and hiltViewModel()?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, viewmodel, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

As far as I can tell when using Jetpack Compose with Hilt there are two ways of creating/accessing a viewModel instance; viewModel() and hiltViewModel(). I can't understand which should be used as they seem to do the same thing. The [documentation for viewModel()](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt) suggests that it automatically uses the View Model that Hilt constructs with @HiltViewModel. So what exactly is the difference between these two implementations and when should each be used?